# Method '...' is too complex to analyze by data flow algorithm and method optimization

Tags: java, spring

I have a method that sets data in the Builder pattern of the `Movie` DTO. The problem is that this method is a bit complicated and IntelliJ shows a warning.

```
private static Movie.Builder initMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity) {
    final Movie.Builder builder = (Movie.Builder) new Movie.Builder(
            movieEntity.getTitle(),
            movieEntity.getType()
    )
            .withId(movieEntity.getId().toString());

    movieEntity.getRating().ifPresent(builder::withRating);
    movieEntity.getRating().ifPresent(ratings -> builder.withNumberOfRating(movieEntity.getRatings().size()));
    final Optional<String> locatedTitle = movieEntity.getOtherTitles().stream()
            .filter(ot -> ot.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED)
            .map(ServiceUtils::toOtherTitleDto)
            .filter(ot -> ot.getCountry() != null
                    && ot.getCountry().getCode().equals(Locale.getDefault().getCountry()))
            .map(OtherTitle::getTitle)
            .findFirst();
    locatedTitle.ifPresent(builder::withTitleLocated);
    final Supplier<Stream<ReleaseDate>> releaseDateStream = () -> movieEntity.getReleaseDates().stream()
            .filter(ot -> ot.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED)
            .map(ServiceUtils::toReleaseDateDto);
    Optional<ReleaseDate> releaseDate = releaseDateStream.get()
            .filter(rd -> rd.getCountry().getCode().equals(Locale.getDefault().getCountry()))
            .findFirst();
    if(releaseDate.isPresent()) {
        builder.withReleaseDate(releaseDate.get());
    } else {
        releaseDate = releaseDateStream.get()
                .filter(rd -> movieEntity.getCountries().stream()
                        .filter(c -> c.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED)
                        .map(ServiceUtils::toCountryDto)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
                        .map(Country::getCountry)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .contains(rd.getCountry()))
                .findFirst();
        if(releaseDate.isPresent()) {
            builder.withReleaseDate(releaseDate.get());
        } else {
            releaseDate = releaseDateStream.get().findFirst();
            builder.withReleaseDate(releaseDate.orElse(null));
        }
    }
    builder.withCountries(movieEntity.getCountries().stream().filter(c -> c.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED).map(MovieCountryEntity::getCountry).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    builder.withLanguages(movieEntity.getLanguages().stream().filter(l -> l.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED).map(MovieLanguageEntity::getLanguage).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    builder.withGenres(movieEntity.getGenres().stream().filter(g -> g.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED).map(MovieGenreEntity::getGenre).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    builder.withBoxofficeCumulative(movieEntity.getBoxOffices().stream().filter(bo -> bo.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED).map(MovieBoxOfficeEntity::getBoxOffice).reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(null));
    builder.withOutline(movieEntity.getOutlines().stream().filter(o -> o.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED).map(MovieOutlineEntity::getOutline).findFirst().orElse(null));
    builder.withSummary(movieEntity.getSummaries().stream().filter(s -> s.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED).map(MovieSummaryEntity::getSummary).findFirst().orElse(null));
    return builder;
}
```

Intellij shows me a warning

```
Method 'initMovieDto' is too complex to analyze by data flow algorithm less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
```

Do you have an idea how to optimize this method? In this method I have to set up so much data in the DTO `Movie` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Method is too complex to analyze by data flow algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979353/error-method-is-too-complex-to-analyze-by-data-flow-algorithm)

Comment: Note that while this is 'only' a warning, it is usually a sign of bad / cluttered design. One potential way to reduce the complexity of your method is to split it into several smaller ones: one for finding `locatedTitle`, one for `releaseDate`, etc. See also [this page](http://wiki.c2.com/?ExtractMethod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn the chunks computing different values into seperate methods.
E.g. wrap the computation of `locatedTitle` into a method:

```
private Optional<String> locatedTitle(MovieEntity movieEntity) {
  return movieEntity.getOtherTitles().stream()
    .filter(ot -> ot.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED)
    .map(ServiceUtils::toOtherTitleDto)
    .filter(ot -> ot.getCountry() != null
        && ot.getCountry().getCode().equals(Locale.getDefault().getCountry()))
    .map(OtherTitle::getTitle)
    .findFirst();
}
```

Then in you main method, instead of that whole block, just a have a simple call:

```
Optional<String> locatedTitle = locatedTitle(movieEntity);
```

Then do the same for that chunk calculating the `releaseDate` if it's not originally present.
Rinse and repeat until the main method is small and easy to read.

This is a good principle in general: have smaller methods doing one thing only. They'll be easier to compose, test and refactor.